# How to crop the image from bottom using opencv python

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to divide the image into two 
1) till bottom text one image
2) from text till end another image.

I have no clue where to start off with, gone through few answers but still confused.

[image: Please find the original image]

After cropping i want it in a way like

[image: Top one]

**The below image is separated**

[image: Bottom one]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply create 2 subimages based on pixel values.

You can do this with `subimage = image[Y_start : Y_end, X_start : X_end]`.

The code below gives this result:

[image]

```
# load image
img = cv2.imread("map.png")

# create sub images
img_map = img[0:600, 0:600]
img_legend = img[600:705, 0:600]

#show images - to save the images, uncomment the lines below.
cv2.imshow("map", img_map)
cv2.imshow("legend", img_legend)
# cv2.imwrite('map_only.png',img_map)
# cv2.imwrite('legend_only.png',img_legend)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: What if every image dimension differs ?

Answer (score 4):

you can define a crop margin based on pixels and assign it to a new variable:

```
src_img = cv2.imread(image_file)


crop_img = src_img[h_start : h_end, w_start : w_end]

cv2.imshow("original", src_img )
cv2.imshow("cropped", crop_img)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: copy() is definitely NOT needed. by specifying the pixel range the Roi is returned as a copy, the original image is not affected. There is an example in this [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.5/d3/df2/tutorial_py_basic_ops.html) that shows this.